# Self Host WCF SOAP Service is serialising objects using the private variables rather than the public ones

Tags: c#, soap, datacontractserializer

I have a very basic self host WCF console application hosting a SOAP service. Unfortunately when I look at the response to a call to a method in the service, the serialized response is actually the serialized private variables rather than the public ones. The client making the calls doesn't expect this so doesn't see any valid values in the response. Code for the service is below:

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), baseAddress))
{
    // Enable metadata publishing.
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    host.Open();

    ... ...
}

public class MyService: IMyService
{
    public MyReturnType MyMethod()
    {
        return new MyReturnType(); 
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")][System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.aaa123.com/WebServices")]
 public partial class MyReturnType {

    private string myPropertyField;

    public string MyProperty { get { return myPropertyField; } set { this.myPropertyField = value; } }
```

So in the call to MyMethod above I would see the property in the response XML defined as myPropertyField, rather than MyProperty.

Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It seems if I add the attribute below on the method declaration in the interface, the response is serialised correctly:

System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults = true)]